# SQL column default value set using row wise operations

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, database-design, date-arithmetic

Is it possible to set a default value in a SQL column to be consisted of other columns? For example, in the table below is it possible to have the EndDate default to StartDate + NoOfDays? So when inserting, I just need to do INSERT INTO xxx VALUES StartDate NoOfDays.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
create table mytable (
    startdate datetime not null,
    noofdays int not null,
    enddate datetime as (startdate + interval noofdays day)
);
```

You would then insert as follows:

```
insert into mytable (startdate, noofdays) values(now(), 3);
```

Which generates:

```
startdate           | noofdays | enddate            
:------------------ | -------: | :------------------
2020-12-12 01:28:27 |        3 | 2020-12-15 01:28:27
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=214f3a9aba5d1981e4066ef0f51b09af)**

Note that this not exactly the same thing as *default*, which you mentioned in the question. A default applies to regular column, and is used only when no value is provided at `insert` time. On the other hand, a generated column cannot be directly written to.

---

**Edit**

In SQL Server:

```
create table mytable (
    startdate datetime not null,
    noofdays int not null,
    enddate as dateadd(day, noofdays, startdate)
)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=751094038de15867a76d82313c475bb2)**

Comment: @Denzyl . . . Just note that this isn't exactly how your question is interpreted.  This defines a "virtual" column that always has the computed value.  It is not a *default* value but simply the value of the column.  That appears to be what you want, but it is not what the question is asking for.  A "default" implies that you can use `update` to change the value after at some later time.